# Pandas Dataframe Pivot Table with Columns Sorted by Range of Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot-table

I need to make a pivot table where the columns are ranges of datetimes. Perhaps I worded my question poorly so I couldn't find the answer I need.

For example say I have dataframe:

```
start_time             end_time               duration_hours    error
2020-05-08 20:04:00    2020-05-08 22:04:00    2                 1
2020-05-09 07:22:00    2020-05-09 08:52:00    1.5               1
2020-05-09 13:20:00    2020-05-09 15:20:00    3                 1
2020-05-08 11:45:00    2020-05-08 15:45:00    4                 2
2020-05-08 18:30:00    2020-05-08 19:00:00    0.5               3
2020-05-09 18:15:00    2020-05-09 20:45:00    2.5               3
```

I want the result to be:

```
         timeframe
error    2020-05-08 06:00 ~ 2020-05-08 18:00    2020-05-08 18:00 ~ 2020-05-09 06:00    2020-05-09 06:00 ~ 2020-05-09 18:00    2020-05-09 18:00 ~ 2020-05-10 06:00
1        0                                      2                                      4.5                                    0
2        4                                      0                                      0                                      0
3        0                                      0.5                                    0                                      2.5
```

Basically, I want error as index, and columns organized by alternating periods of 6am-6pm and 6pm-6am each day. Data in the table should be the sum of the duration within that period. It's ok to assume that start_time and end_time would both be within the same period.

I've been trying to figure out how to organize the columns by alternating periods but failed. The table needs to be scalable so I can't hard code it either. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: @PoHuang did I answer your question. Can you accept as answer by clicking the checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

You might not necessarily need to add a range, as it seems clear based off the the value of the next column. I would groupby with `error` and `pd.Grouper`. Then, create a pivot table from there.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['error', pd.Grouper(key='start_time', freq='12H', base=6)])['duration_hours'].sum().reset_index().pivot_table(index='error', columns='start_time', values='duration_hours').fillna(0)
```

df1

```
start_time  2020-05-08 06:00:00  2020-05-08 18:00:00    2020-05-09 06:00:00  2020-05-09 18:00:00
error               
1           0.0                  2.0                    4.5                  0.0
2           4.0                  0.0                    0.0                  0.0
3           0.0                  0.5                    0.0                  2.5
```